# Filling Shipping address fields with values using Jquery or Knockout Js

Tags: magento2, jquery, knockoutjs

Is it possible to just fill the shipping address fields with my own values?

For example, I want city field to be filled with "My City" when an event occurs on the checkout page. I know the checkout page uses Knockout JS, but I haven't figured out how to pass values to the fields themselves.

So far, I have jQuery running on the checkout page but writing code:

```
$('input[name="shippingAddress.city"]').val("My city");
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. It works fine in my case.

require(['jquery'], function($){

```
    var onDomIsRendered = function(domString) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            function waitUntil() {
              setTimeout(function() {
                if($(domString).length > 0){
                  resolve($(domString));
                }else {
                  waitUntil();
                }
              }, 4000);
            }
            //start the loop
            waitUntil();
          });
        };

        onDomIsRendered("#shipping-new-address-form").then(function(element){               
            $('[name="city"]').val('My city');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Shipping address from update value by event keyup so you can try:

```
$('input[name="shippingAddress.city"]').val("My city").keyup();
```